# Have bash script wait for password

Tags: shell, ssh, background-process

I want to write a little script which sets up a socks proxy via ssh and then starts a browser using that proxy.

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh -D 1234 user@host #&
chromium-browser --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:1234"
```

If I add the `&`-sign at the end of the first line the script just asks for my password and then opens an `ssh` terminal. The browser is started not before the ssh terminal is closed which is pretty useless. If I add the `&`-sign the script doesn't wait until I typed in the password and I don't know how I can cleanly end the `ssh` session.

I don't want to use automatic `ssh` login via `rsa`-keys.

Any suggestions how I could circumvent the problems described above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be interested in the `-f` option to ssh which makes it go to the background once the password has been obtained.

Comment: Thanks, but this gives me a `Cannot fork into background without a command to execute` error.

Comment: Using `-f -N` worked.

Comment: What's the best way to end an `ssh` session started this way?

Comment: @student `kill` it

Comment: Is it possible to kill it automatically when the browser window is closed?

Comment: Add `ssh_pid=$!` after `ssh` and add `kill $ssh_pid` after the browser.

Answer (score 3):

I would read the password from the terminal (with read -s) and

```
echo $password | ssh -f -N -D ....
```

Comment: Hello world about how to get pass with read command: ```$ read -s -p "Password: " myPass; echo "Password informed is: $myPass"```